# Share installed requirements between jobs

Tags: pip, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have the following *yml* configuration file with 3 different jobs:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - analyze

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - coverage run --source='.' manage.py test
  cache:
    paths:
      - .coverage

analyze:
  stage: analyze
  script:
    - flake8
    - coverage report
```

In the first job I install the requirements, among which are *coverage* or *flake8*. But these tools are used in the following jobs. I have tried using 'dependencies' or 'cache', but it didn't work: only files/dirs under the project root directory can be shared, not the binaries under /user/local/bin.

I have tried to indicate another directory for *pip install*, but the binary is installed in /user/local/bin.

The workaround I have found is to install the dependencies in each job, but I think that this is the less optimal solution.

I think that there must be a better solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution, at least for *python3* (enough for me):

*python3* has a built-in tool for managing virtual envs: *venv*

Using *venv*, we can create the virtual env in the project root dir, cache this dir, and enable our virtual env in each job.

```
variables:
  VENV_NAME: "env"

cache:
  paths:
    - $VENV_NAME

first_job:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
    - python3 -m venv $VENV_NAME
    - source $VENV_NAME/bin/activate
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt

next_jobs:
  script:
    - source $VENV_NAME/bin/activate
    - echo "hello world!"
```

PD: don't forget to exclude virtual env dir from coverage or other analysis tools